# Calling server side method using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to test a function that is on the server side by calling it from the client side using AJAX.

I get this error every time I invoke the AJAX method:

*http://localhost:5958/myaccount/notifications/myaccount/notifications/Default.aspx/method Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

Here's my AJAX function:

```
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myaccount/notifications/Default.aspx/method",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

HTML control :

```
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
    onclick="ShowCurrentTime()" />
```

Function I'm trying to call on the server side:

```
        [WebMethod]
    protected bool method()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

**Update**

Changed the url to : `'<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx/method") %>'` and now I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error.

**Update2**

The internal error was due to [HttpPost] attribute which I changed to [WebMethod] and it works.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms Try creating the URL for the target WebMethod the way it's done there rather than hardcoding it

Comment: @IanGilroy changed the url to :  <%= ResolveUrl("~/myaccount/notifications/Default.aspx/method") %> and now I'm getting this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'notifications'

Comment: maybe you can refer to another link like this: [ajax call jquery asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414726/asp-net-mvc-and-jquery-get-info-to-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your **url**.

Use a leading slash(/) like following.

```
url:"/myaccount/notifications/Default.aspx/method"
```

Comment: Okay I have include a leading slash. I'm getting 500 (Internal Server Error) now

Answer (score 1):

Your server side call must be static public.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(v=vs.90).aspx

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool method()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: try to set your url to 'Default.aspx/method'

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not passing any parameter. So can you try Data:{} instead of Data:"{}".